# Howto map SVN User to Jenkins people

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm using the ActiveDirectory plugin for Jenkins, so that users have to sign in to Jenkins with their credentials. The user is then called joe.doe in Jenkins, which is perfect.

When the same person checks in new code, Jenkins detects the user as MyCompany.com\joe.doe, so it creates another user instead of mapping change to the user joe.doe. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Is there a way to cut off the MyCompany.com part from the SVN user?

Comment: When you run commands such as `svn log` and `svn info` does it display the `MyCompany.com` prefix for people?

Comment: yes svn log displays mycompany.com\joe.doe

Answer (score 1):

The only way to fix it, as far as I understand, is to talk to your SVN administrator to get rid of the prefix.

Comment: this is a problem, since the company is big and it would affect many developers.

Comment: I'll have another look it Jenkins has hooks/plugins to preprocess the names coming from SVN, but AFAIK there are none at this stage.